# How to supply two arrays as DataRow parameters?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to write a unit test that will compare two arrays. I have defined the unit test as so:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(
    new[] { "COM3", "COM1", "COM2" },
    new[] { "COM1", "COM2", "COM3" }
)]
...
public void TestCOMPortSorting(string[] unorderedPorts, string[] expectedOrderedPorts)
```

However, my IDE throws the following error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

I have tried using external variables, defining the arrays as `new string[]`, creating a single array with these arrays, all with no luck.

How can I use these two arrays as parameters for my unit test?

Comment: You need to add row to a table dt.Rows.Add(new[] { "COM3", "COM1", "COM2" });

Comment: I face this issue now and I can see that everything works fine if I add any 3rd argument. One array also works fine. I assume that it's something with the 'param's overload of the DataRow that can't decipher two arrays but I don't know how to tell the compiler this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For such complex data, change to using the `DynamicData` attribute

> This attribute allows to get the values of the parameters from a method or a property. The method or the property must return an `IEnumerable<object[]>`. Each row corresponds to the values of a test.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestDataMethod), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void TestCOMPortSorting(string[] unorderedPorts, string[] expectedOrderedPorts) {
    //...
}

static IEnumerable<object[]> TestDataMethod() {
    return new[] {
        new []{ new[] { "COM3", "COM1", "COM2" }, new[] { "COM1", "COM2", "COM3" } } //a data row
    };
}
```

Reference  [MSTest v2: Data tests](https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-data-tests.htm)

Comment: How have I not know about this magical `DynamicDataAttribute`??? 

Answer (score 3):

`DataRowAttribute` can handle arrays of simple types. The issue here is that `DataRowAttribute` has the following overload for more than one parameters: `DataRowAttribute(object data1, params object[] moreData)`.

In your expression, I think C# takes the second string array as the `object[] moreData` and it doesn't like it. If you specify the `params object[]` argument explicitly it will take the second string array as expected.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(
    new[] { "COM3", "COM1", "COM2" },
    new object[] { new[] { "COM1", "COM2", "COM3" } }
)]
...
public void TestCOMPortSorting(string[] unorderedPorts, string[] expectedOrderedPorts)
```

Note that if you have any other 3rd argument it works without the workaround.